# $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with compact support, equality of derivates

Tags: analysis

> Let $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ i.e. 2 times continuously differentiable with compact support. Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{j,k=1}^n|\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}|^2\,d\lambda_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\sum_{j=1}^n|\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j^2})^2\,d\lambda_n$.

I don't even have an intuition for why this could be right so where do I start here?

Comment: Interesting corollary: harmonic functions in the whole space can't have compact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to show it by using the Fouriertransformation of $f$ and then using Plancherel's theorem in both versions ($||f||_2=||\mathcal{F}f||_2$ and $<f,g>=<\mathcal{F}f,\mathcal{F}g>$ in $L^2$).